# Which DOS game do these sprites of a little character and dragon come from?

Tags: game-identification, msdos

[image: sprite 1]

[image: sprite 2]

There's a character and a dragon-creature. I'm wondering which game these images are from.

Answer (score 12):

Those are from Master of Magic.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_of_Magic

See this image for comparison https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/d/d1/MoM_Node_Battle.gif

Comment: Specifically those appear to be a sky drake from the tactical battle screen and an orc rebel from the city screen. (I've played way too much MOM over the years)

Comment: I played a lot 20 years ago and I pretty much always got Life Magic, summoned Thorin the Chosen, put all spells on him and then conquered everything with my one man army :) Great game.